Fulfilling commitment
Area51 stats:
committed users
315 users committed
75.9% signed up for beta
7% fulfilled commitment  
Only 7% of the people who committed to the site actively participated for 3 months and asked/answered 10 questions.  That's 17 / 239 who signed up for the beta.  What can we do to get the remaining 222 people to be more active?

We do send out an automatic, gentle nag reminder mail to those users who do not fulfill their commitment, or even visit the site.
I think I'd focus on promoting the site through the traditional methods:
Will this site be closed again? Is there a possibility of continuing it elsewhere?

Other sites with low fulfilled commitment percentages are Startup Business and Code Review. Note that the former has a lot of Excellent metrics whereas the latter is mostly Okay. So I doubt the percent of fulfillment is predictive.

Startup Business has a long history before SE 2.0, so I wouldn't take it as a representative case.

Based on my experience on the SharePoint site, I suspect that the formula for fulfilling one's commitment has changed. It used to be answer 10+ questions but now appears to be answer 10+ non-wiki questions and get 200+ reputation. 
